# How to solve these errors that appear while running update.php (during upgrade from Drupal 6 to 7)?

Tags: 7, updating

Can someone shed me some light regarding this error?

> The following updates returned messages
>
> taxonomy module
>
> Update #7007
>   Failed: DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Cannot add index name to table taxonomy_term_data: index already exists. in DatabaseSchema_mysql->addIndex() (line 432 of /var/www/vhosts/drupal7upgrade/includes/database/mysql/schema.inc).
>
> services module
>
> Update #7301
>   Failed: DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Cannot add field services_endpoint.debug: field already exists. in DatabaseSchema_mysql->addField() (line 323 of /var/www/vhosts/drupal7upgrade/includes/database/mysql/schema.inc).
>
> search module
>
> Update #7000
>   Failed: DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Cannot add primary key to table search_dataset: primary key already exists. in DatabaseSchema_mysql->addPrimaryKey() (line 392 of /var/www/vhosts/drupal7upgrade/includes/database/mysql/schema.inc).

I'm getting thes errors when attempting to run update.php while upgrading from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7.

Comment: I'm getting similar errors, but when doing a DB update. Did you ever figure out a solution?